# Manipulate Error

Tags: plotting, manipulate, warning-messages

I have the following code, which allows me to compile specific `Manipulate` plots on a separate plot. Unfortunately, I have a small syntax error which I can't seem to fix. The exception raised is:

> Manipulate::vsform: Manipulate Tracked symbol does not have the correct form for a
> variable specification.

Code:

```
Constants

au = QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "AstronomicalUnit"], "Meters"];
c = QuantityMagnitude@
   UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"], "MetersPerSecond"];
Qpr = 1;
Lsun = QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarLuminosity"], "Watts"];
Rsun = QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarRadius"], "Meters"];
Msun = QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarMass"], "Kilograms"];
G = QuantityMagnitude@
   UnitConvert[
    Quantity[1, "GravitationalConstant"], ("Meters"^2 "Newtons")/
     "Kilograms"^2];
year = QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "Years"], "Seconds"];
Myr = year*10^6;
Gyr = year*10^9;
Mwd = 0.6*Msun;
Cst = 1.27;
U = 1*10^17;

Functions

L[t_] := 3.26*Lsun*(Mwd/(0.6*Msun))*(0.1 + t/Myr)^-1.18;
Roche[dens_] := 0.65*Cst*Rsun*(Mwd/(0.6*Msun))^(1/3)*(dens/3000)^(-1/3);
Papsis[t_] := a[t] (1 - e[t]);

Radiative Drag

(*Parametrically vary R, where rho=2000kgm^-3*)

RDdadtRρa = -((3 L[t] Qpr (2 + 3 e[t]^2))/(
   c^2 (16 π 2000 Rast a[t] (1 - e[t]^2)^(3/2))));
RDdedtRρa = -((15 L[t] e[t])/(
   c^2 (32 π Rast 2000 a[t]^2 Sqrt[1 - e[t]^2])));

(*solving radiative drag eq's with Rast, ρ, and a0 parameter*)

RDsolRρa = 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[{a'[t] == RDdadtRρa, e'[t] == RDdedtRρa, 
    a[0] == a0, e[0] == 3/10}, {a, e}, {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, {Rast, ρ, a0}];

fRDticks = {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1/Myr}], 
    Automatic}};

Manipulate[Column[{
   Style["Working Plot", Bold],
   Plot[fun[func, t], {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, FrameTicks -> fRDticks, 
    PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.01]]}],
   Style["Compiled Plot", Bold],
   If[comp === {},
    Plot[fun[func, t], {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, FrameTicks -> fRDticks, 
     PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.01]]}],
    Plot[comp, {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, FrameTicks -> fRDticks, 
     PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.01]]}]]}],

 (*controls*)

 {{func, 1}, {1 -> "a", 2 -> "e", 3 -> "q"}}, {{Rast, 0.005}, 0.0001, 0.1, 
  0.001, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{ρ, 3000}, 1000, 7000, 50, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{a0, 10, "a0 (au)"}, 3, 20, 0.2, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, TrackedSymbols -> {func, Rast, ρ, a0},
 Button["Append", AppendTo[comp, fun[func, t]]],
 Button["Reset", comp = {}],

 (*options for Manipulate*)

 Initialization :> {comp = {}, 
   fun[sel_, t_] := 
    Switch[sel, 1, RDsolRρa[Rast, ρ, a0*au][[1]][t], 2, 
     RDsolRρa[Rast, ρ, a0*au][[2]][t], 3, 
     RDsolRρa[Rast, ρ, a0*au][[1]][
       t] (1 - RDsolRρa[Rast, ρ, a0*au][[2]][t])]}]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you remove the TrackedSymbols->{ } command then it appears to function.

Comment: @bills If i do that, changing the parameter values doesn't alter the plot.

Comment: Options should come at the end.  Move `TrackedSymbols` after the last `Button`.  (The hint is that the error message indicates that `Manipulate` is not parsing the option as an option, but as a variable/control declaration.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 That works perfectly now! Thank you!

Comment: Okay! :) Glad it worked out.